# Float vertical background-image under another background-image

Tags: html, css-float, background-image

Image explanation: http://img219.imageshack.us/f/skrmavbild20110321kl160.png/

I have a background-image that I want on the top of my page, this image is width 800px and height 400px.

Under this image I want another background-image which will repeat vertical (repeat-y) for the rest of the page.

I have tried the following

```
<div id="bg-static">
 <div id="bg-repeat-y">
  <div>
   Text goes here
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The thing is that I want "The text goes here" to float over both element. (See picture, http://img219.imageshack.us/f/skrmavbild20110321kl160.png/)

What should I do to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution would be the other way around: have the repeating background on the outside `div` and the fixed height background on the inside `div`.

Some code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EBK4C/

Comment: Haha, why have'nt I thought of that. So simple fix. But it works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are making this seem too complicated, but it's extremely easy.
This is what you need to do:

Your "infinite, repeated" image will go as a site background, like this:

```
body{ background: url("your-repeated-image.png"); }
```

Next, create a html like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="container">
      any content, text, whatever goes here
   </div>
</body>
```

And just put your 800x400px image there like this:

```
#container{ width: 800px; background: url("your-top-image.png") no-repeat; }
```

While testing it, temporarily use this:

```
#container{ height: 600px; } /* erase after the content is ready */
```